# Problem Accessing XML in a Flex 3 Project when Using IE

Tags: xml, apache-flex

I've got a Flex 3 project that uses xml. It works great in Safari or Firefox. But it blows up in IE. I access the xml using the lines below:

```
 _clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
 _mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
```

If I hard code it like this:

```
_clickURL = "http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=3058997a64__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com";

_mediaSource = "http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&amp;contenttype=png";
```

then it works fine in IE. So, I know that there is a problem in parsing the xml in IE.

My xml is:

```
<adXMLReturn>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript"/>
  <SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ajs.php?zoneid=4&amp;cb=78244247341&amp;charset=utf-8&amp;loc=http%3A//www.mywebsite.com/"/>
  <A href="http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?oaparams=2__bannerid=1__zoneid=4__cb=0416e603aa__oadest=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com" target="_blank">
    <IMG title="" border="0" alt="" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/ai.php?filename=mybanner.png&amp;contenttype=png" width="468" height="60"/>
  </A>
  <DIV style="POSITION: absolute; VISIBILITY: hidden; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" id="beacon_0416e603aa">
    <IMG style="WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 0px" alt="" src="http://www.mywebsite.com/openx/www/delivery/lg.php?bannerid=1&amp;campaignid=1&amp;zoneid=4&amp;loc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F&amp;cb=0416e603aa" width="0" height="0"/>
  </DIV>
  <NOSCRIPT/>
</adXMLReturn>
```

How can I access the xml in a way that IE will accept? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

-Laxmidi

Comment: I set alerts on:
 
_clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
 
In Internet Explorer both variables come back as ""  -- nothing. In Safari and Firefox the correct value is returned.
 
Are the above variables considered E4X? If so, will it work with IE? If not, is there a work around?
 
Thank you.
 
-Laxmidi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've got it now. Shout out to Tadster and Andrew Trice for their help.

This worked in Safari and Firefox:

```
_clickURL = xhtml.a.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.a.img.@src.toString();
```

This worked in IE:

```
_clickURL = xhtml.A.@href.toString();
_mediaSource = xhtml.A.IMG.@src.toString();
```

The adXMLReturn is the same in Safari and IE, except that IE capitalized the HTML tags. When Safari returned the xml, the html tags were lower-case.

-Laxmidi